# android include change textView value

Tags: android, include, textview

I include a layout in my  fragment1.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/family_header"
    layout="@layout/header" />
```

header xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dip"
android:background="#33cc66"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/nav_back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nav_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/nav_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I want to change TextView "nav_text" value dynamically in my Fragment1.class . how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create class that extends fragement....

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rssitem_detail,
        container, false);
    return view;
  }

  public void setText(String item) {
    TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
    view.setText(item);
  }
}
```

in this class you can change value of textview dynemically.....please put your code here.so we can understand what is your actual problem.

Comment: merry chrismas....no its not complex..its easy...please referr this link...
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your fragment oncreateview method like this

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container,false);
    final LinearLayout headerLayout= (LinearLayout ) v.findViewById(R.id.family_header);
             TextView txtHeaderText=(TextView)headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.nav_text);
            txtHeaderText.setText("My New Text");

    return v;

}
```

I hope it's work for you.